# Meaning of 'str1.characters'

Tags: swift, character

During my self Swift 5.1 studies, via Apple's book, I have come across two lines of codes I am not sure what they do.
From the following two lines, I don't understand what the .characters and .characters.count are used for.

I know in swift the '.count' command can be used to count the number of characters in a string, however, I wouldn't know why sometimes '.characters' or '.characters.count' is used.

`//Example code
let str = str1.characters
let str2 = str3.characters.count`

Comment: `str1.characters` returns String where as `str3.characters.count` returns Int

Comment: It means you're using an old version of Swift.  The `characters` property has been removed from String.  You used to have to use `str.characters` to access the characters of a `String`, but now you can use the `String` directly.  `str3.characters.count` is now just `str3.count` and you can get the characters with a for loop: `for c in str { print(c) }`

Comment: Just to add on, the reason why they called `.characters` first was because `.count` (or a similar function) would not actually return the number of characters accurately. Some more complicated characters (like emojis) might count as two characters rather than one. Typically this is not ideal behavior, which is why they would call `.characters` first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift 5.1 and above (and some earlier versions of Swift, but I'm not sure which ones), the `characters` property has been removed. @vacawama's comment is correct, in that it *used* to provide an array of the string's characters, but you can now do that correctly.

In short: It's from an old version of Swift, and its functionality has been moved directly to `String`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `characters` never returned an *array* but a *collection.*

Comment: @MartinR true, however, as the OP said that they were learning Swift, I simplified it to the first type conforming to `Collection` that they would learn about

Answer (score 3):

```
str1.characters
```

it return array of characters of str1

```
 str3.characters.count
```

it returns integer that is number of characters in str3.